Brother DCP-7030 scanner is not recognized by Ubuntu 22.04 /24.04
The scanner in my USB-connected Brother DCP7030 multi-function device stopped working when I upgraded my Lubuntu to 22.04. In an attempt to get it working, I upgraded further to 24.04, but it still refuses to play ball. The printer in the MFD still works fine.
I've installed the Brother drivers and fix to run as admin mode from the brother website.
https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp7030_all&os=128
but it still refuses to be visible to SANE.
$ dpkg -l  |  grep  Brother
ii  brother-udev-rule-type1       1.0.2          all          Brother udev rule type 1
ii  brscan3           0.2.13-1                  amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  printer-driver-brlaser  6-3build2      amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04f9:01ea Brother Industries, Ltd DCP-7030
sane-find-scanner
found possible USB scanner (vendor=0x04f9, product=0x01ea) at libusb:001:008
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
  Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported   
  by SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

$ scanimage -L
No scanners were identified. 
If you were expecting something different, check that the scanner is plugged in,   
turned on and detected by the sane-find-scanner tool


Which Scanner driver did you install? Did you install all of the 3 files: Scanner driver 64bit (deb package), Scan-key-tool 64bit (deb package) and Scanner Setting file (deb package)?

Hi thanks for your comment. I've installed the Scanner driver (64 bit deb package) and the Scanner Setting file (deb package). I didn't install the scan-key-tool as this was just to enable the scan button on the front panel of the scanner, which I don't use.

Made some progress on this issue. It appears that 24.04 looks for scanner information in  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/   rather than  /usr/lib/sane/ . I moved the brother files into this new directory and scanimage -L now finds the scanner successfully.

However, sane-find-scanner cannot open the device - access denied (insufficient permissions). When run as sudo, sane-find-scanner now detects the device but errors with "could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error".

Please update your question with all the new information.

See this question and answer for a problem with the snap version of Simple Scan.
